# python proxy server, json request

Tags: python, json

I have a proxy server querying sites.  My previous code queried txt files and I want to query for a different site for a json object.  I'm not sure if the txt/json is the problem, but one works fine while the other does not.  Below is a portion of the pertinent portion of the code.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy_full_auth_string})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


filelist = list()
filelist.append('http://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_us_and_census.txt')
filelist.append('https://cadatacatalog.state.gov/storage/f/2013-11-24T20:56:10.098Z/validpassportsbyyear.json')

for url in filelist:
   filename = url.split('/')[-1]
   fhand = open(filename, 'w')
   print('Retrieving', url)
   uh = urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

Response: the txt file works fine, however I get an error for the json one:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Comment: Could it be due the second url being in http not https (thus not defined in the proxy)? Just a guess. I don't know ProxyHandler.

Comment: Changed it to http:......, checked in browser to make sure it worked (it did), then ran in script. Same error.